# Bash - Split string into array, preserving spaces

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to split a string into an array using a delimiter other than space, keeping spaces preserved.

For example, if I run:

```
files=$(echo "foo.txt:bar.txt:my story.txt" | tr ":" "\n")
for f in $files; do
    echo $f
done
```

I get:

```
foo.txt
bar.txt
my
story.txt
```

How can I preserve the spaces?

Comment: I believe that the spaces are preserved in the above code. Test it again.

Comment: @VenkateshMarepalli It split `my story.txt` into `my` and `story.txt`

Comment: @VenkateshMarepalli, why would you expect spaces to be preserved? The unquoted expansion is subject to string splitting. See the output from ideone's online interpreter at https://ideone.com/kTj9A7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`files=$(cmd)` is not an array assignment. It's a string assignment (the output of `cmd` is assigned to a regular variable `files`).

I would recommend using `read -a` to split the string as globs won't be an issue:

```
IFS=: read -ra files <<< "foo.txt:bar.txt:my story.txt"

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IFS` to specify the field separator:

```
IFS=: files=($(echo "foo.txt:bar.txt:my story.txt"))
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

You also need to put parentheses around the value to make an array. You just set `$files` to a string where the `:` were replaced with newline. When you then expand `$files`, word splitting uses any form of whitespace, so spaces and newlines are field separators.

Comment: Need to disable globbing for this to be safe.

Comment: Also note that `IFS` will be changed.

Comment: It will not be changed. It's specified as a variable only for a specific command execution. You can try it out:

`IFS=: files=($(echo "foo.txt:bar.txt:my story.txt")); echo ${IFS}; echo ${files[2]}`

To me this is a very good answer.